# How to pass variables from xs javascript to ABAP function

Tags: javascript, abap, hana

I have been give the task of passing ABAP to xs Javascript.
This will use and ODATA service where a POST request with body.data will have an object with headers and an array of objects that I will be able to use in the following format:

```
{
   "IvCompCode":"1710",
   "IvDocType":"NB",
   "IvPurchOrg":"1710",
   "IvPurGroup":"002",
   "IvVendor":"17386001",
   "ItemsSet":[
      {
         "Ebelp":"00010",
         "Matnr":"MZ-RM-M500-09",
         "Werks":"1710",
         "Lgort":"171S",
         "Menge":"5.000",
         "Netpr":"100.000"
      },
      {
         "Ebelp":"00020",
         "Matnr":"MZ-RM-M500-07",
         "Werks":"1710",
         "Lgort":"171S",
         "Menge":"4.000",
         "Netpr":"105.000"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can call the ABAP function inside the javascript function, however, I have no idea how to pass the variables from the ODATA service and then simply put them inside the ABAP function, while also keeping them in the javascript function so they can be used in another logic. Here's what I have right now:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function callABAPMethod()
{
<%
  DATA: po_header          LIKE bapimepoheader,
        poheaderx          LIKE bapimepoheaderx,
        tab_poitem         TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapimepoitem,
        tab_poitemx        TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapimepoitemx,
        tab_poitem_struct  LIKE bapimepoitem,
        tab_poitemx_struct LIKE bapimepoitemx,
        ebelp_num(5)       TYPE n,
        ebelp_char(5)      TYPE c.


  po_header-comp_code = iv_comp_code.
  po_header-doc_type  = iv_doc_type.
  po_header-vendor = iv_vendor.
  po_header-purch_org = iv_purch_org.
  po_header-pur_group = iv_pur_group.


  poheaderx-comp_code = 'X'.
  poheaderx-doc_type = 'X'.
  poheaderx-vendor = 'X'.
  poheaderx-purch_org = 'X'.
  poheaderx-pur_group = 'X'.



  LOOP AT zpoitems INTO DATA(item).
    CLEAR: tab_poitem_struct, tab_poitemx_struct.

    tab_poitem_struct-po_item = item-ebelp.
    tab_poitem_struct-material = item-matnr.
    tab_poitem_struct-plant = item-werks.
    tab_poitem_struct-stge_loc = item-lgort.
    tab_poitem_struct-quantity = item-menge.
    tab_poitem_struct-net_price = item-netpr.


    tab_poitemx_struct-po_item = item-ebelp.
    tab_poitemx_struct-po_itemx = 'X'.
    tab_poitemx_struct-material = 'X'.
    tab_poitemx_struct-plant = 'X'.
    tab_poitemx_struct-stge_loc = 'X'.
    tab_poitemx_struct-quantity = 'X'.
    tab_poitemx_struct-net_price = 'X'.

    APPEND tab_poitem_struct TO tab_poitem.
    APPEND tab_poitemx_struct TO tab_poitemx.


  ENDLOOP.


  IF iv_update EQ 'X'.
    IF  iv_po_number IS NOT INITIAL.
      CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_PO_CHANGE'
        EXPORTING
          purchaseorder = iv_po_number
          poheader      = po_header
          poheaderx     = poheaderx
        TABLES
          return        = return
          poitem        = tab_poitem
          poitemx       = tab_poitemx.

      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT' .
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ELSE.
    CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_PO_CREATE1'
      EXPORTING
        poheader         = po_header
        poheaderx        = poheaderx
      IMPORTING
        exppurchaseorder = po_numer
      TABLES
        return           = et_return
        poitem           = tab_poitem
        poitemx          = tab_poitemx.

    IF sy-subrc = 0.
      CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
%>
}


</script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you doing exactly. In the title you want to pass from JS to ABAP, and the you write "I was given a task of passing ABAP to xs Javascript". i.e. exactly opposite.

Comment: what is XS JS? HANA server-side XS app?

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom oData service for cathing ABAP codes in backend which are sending from js. Use SEGW t-code for creating custom service and implement your own ABAP code for catching request. Some of sample blog [here](https://www.erpworkbench.com/sap-webapps/segw-odata-gateway-service.htm).

On backend side you can create dynamic program in run time on ABAP side but generally not approved by system admins. Your request may be catched by code scan tools. It has risk because of, someone manipulate your code and change your codes to access system without privileges.

Check the [GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapgenerate_subroutine_pool.htm) statement for running dynamic ABAP code in runtime.

Comment: How generating subroutine pool will help him to pass JS->ABAP->JS? For what it's worth subroutines are obsoleted and shouldn't be used anymore

Comment: @Suncatcher, userr asking keeping ABAP code in JS and sending ABAP code as parameter (my understanding). I added detail about sending parameters.

Comment: It is not clear in which environment he runs his JS in. If he use ODATA he definitely knows how to pass Odata parameters, and subroutine pool has nothing to do with his task (which is unclear yet)